# Get current time as ulong amount of minutes since 01.01.2001 00:00 in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

How do I get the current UTC time in ulong number of minutes since 01.01.2001 00:00 in c#? I know it involves DateTime.UtcNow property but how do I get the offset in minutes?

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? (Hint - you can subtract one `DateTime` from another to get a `TimeSpan`...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
ulong totalMinutes = (ulong) (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(2001,1,1,0,0,0,0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Not within the range of `DateTime`.  `double` has enough bits in the mantissa to correctly represent every possible number of minutes in the entire range of `DateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DateTime.UtcNow function combined to a TimeSpan :

```
        DateTime reference = new DateTime(2001, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - reference.Ticks);
        ulong minutesCount = Convert.ToUInt64(duration.TotalMinutes);
```

Comment: Why work from ticks instead of just subtracting the timespans directly?

Comment: The `new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - reference.Ticks);` step is really unnecessary. Either just go from ticks to minutes directly (`(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - reference.Ticks) / 10000 / 1000 / 60`) or subtract the DateTime's directly.